# Issue using NHibernate's DateDiff

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I am using the following HQL in code

```
string sPastDueForCustomer = @"select 
    inv.fInvoiceDate as fInvoiceDate,
    cust.fName as fCustomerName,
    inv.fInvoiceNumberDisplay as fInvoiceNumberDisplay,
    inv.fBalance as fBalance,   
    inv.fDueDate as fDueDate,
    datediff(day, :GenerateDate, inv.fDueDate) as fDaysPastDue
    FROM tARInvoice as inv INNER JOIN inv.Customer as cust
    Where inv.fDueDate < :GenerateDate - " 
    + 
    ARApplicationSetup[0].fGracePeriod 
    + 
    @"  
    And inv.fInvoiceType= 'Manual'  
    And inv.fCustomerID = :CustomerID  
    And inv.fBalance > 0  
    And inv.fIsPosted = 1  
    And inv.fIsVoided = 0";                

    //get the result of query and return the object of PaymentInvoiceDetails
    IList<tARInvoice> PastDueForCustomer = 
        Session.CreateQuery(sPastDueForCustomer)
               .SetGuid("CustomerID", CustomerId)
               .SetDateTime("GenerateDate", GenerateDate)
               .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<tARInvoice())
               .List<tARInvoice>();
```

When I run this, I am getting the following error:

```
No data type for node: 
MethodNode (datediff(exprList day ? (tarinvoice0_.fDueDate tarinvoice0_.fARInvoiceID fDueDate)))
[select
    inv.fInvoiceDate as fInvoiceDate,
    cust.fName as fCustomerName,
    inv.fInvoiceNumberDisplay as fInvoiceNumberDisplay,
    inv.fBalance as fBalance,   
    inv.fDueDate as fDueDate
    ,datediff(day, :GenerateDate,inv.fDueDate) as fDaysPastDue 
    FROM tARInvoice as inv INNER JOIN inv.Customer as cust
    Where inv.fDueDate < :GenerateDate - 15  
    And inv.fInvoiceType= 'Manual'  
    And inv.fCustomerID = :CustomerID  
    And inv.fBalance > 0  
    And inv.fIsPosted = 1  
    And inv.fIsVoided = 0]
```

The type of `fDaysPastDue` is `int`.

Comment: Please reformat your question..

Answer (score 0):

In here,

```
WHERE inv.fDueDate < :GenerateDate - " + ARApplicationSetup[0].fGracePeriod + @" ...
```

You are substracting an `int` from a `DateTime`, which turns into this,

```
WHERE inv.fDueDate < :GenerateDate - 15
```

raising an error because the operation involves different types.

Make sure you are using the right type from the `GenerateDate` variable, and set it correctly in your query,

```
Session.CreateQuery(sPastDueForCustomer)
       .SetGuid("CustomerID", CustomerId)
       .SetInt32("GenerateDate", GenerateDate.Days) 
       // instead of: ".SetDateTime(GenerateDate)"
       ...
```